# I need to check a JavaScript array to see if there are any duplicate values.

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var a =["color", "radius", "y", "x", "x", "x"];
```

How to check, that this array does not  have the same elements?

Comment: By "not have the same elements", do you mean you want to check if there are no duplicates?

Comment: but this has same elements. Try to define your question bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var a = ["color", "radius", "y", "x", "x", "x"];
var uniqueval = a.filter(function (itm, i, a) {// array of unique elements
    return i == a.indexOf(itm);
});
if (a.length > uniqueval.length) {
    alert("duplicate elements")
}
else{
    alert('Unique elements')
}
```

**Demos** with [duplicate](http://jsfiddle.net/b58yz/) and [unique](http://jsfiddle.net/b58yz/1/) elements

Answer (score 0):

If the newArray has elements inside it then you have dublicates. You can then remove the elements of newArray from the original Array.

```
var a = ["color", "radius", "y", "x", "x", "x"];
var sortA = a.sort();
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sortA[i + 1] == sortA[i]) {
        newArray.push(sortA[i]);
    }
}

alert(newArray);
```

Comment: If it helped you please accept it as answered or vote it up plz.

Answer (score 0):

This is super simple:

```
var i, a = ["color", "radius", "y", "x", "x", "x"];

for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if(a.indexOf(a[i]) != a.lastIndexOf(a[i]))
          alert("Duplicate found!");
}
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/T3Gr9/)**